# writing f.select with map in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, dictionary, has-many

i am having the associations like this.

```
company has many city_groups 
and city_groups has many cities
```

how can i have the f.select with map method so that in drop_down i can show the city names. and internally i want to save the city id.

```
<%= builder.collection_select :city, @company.city_groups.map{ |city_groups|.each do |city| {city.id city.name} } || [], :id ,:name, {:include_blank=>'<option disabled=true selected=selected >Please Select</option>'.html_safe}, {:class=>"form-control", :id=>"" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work

```
<%= builder.collection_select :city, @company.city_groups.map{ |city| [ city.id, city.name ] }, {:include_blank: true } %>
```